# Check an element doesn't exist after applying a filter in selenium/java

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I have to verify the result that it matches with the filter that I have applied.

The filter I select is "Open" and make sure the result (which is a list) contains only Open.

I thought of using the xpath of the text "Open" but the xpath of each displayed result changes like below:

```
1st result - (//SPAN[@class='ng-binding'][text()='OPEN'][text()='OPEN'])[1]

2nd result - (//SPAN[@class='ng-binding'][text()='OPEN'][text()='OPEN'])[2]

3rd result - (//SPAN[@class='ng-binding'][text()='OPEN'][text()='OPEN'])[3]

and so on...
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

HTML for the 1st Open result:

```
<div class="issues-list-item clearfix"><div class="issue-thumbnail"><div class="thumbnail-img gallery ng-isolate-scope" ng-gallery="" images="IssuesListItemCtrl.issue.attachments" thumbs-num="11" description="IssuesListItemCtrl.issue.description" issuenum="IssuesListItemCtrl.issue.issueNumber"><!-- ngIf: image.thumb -->
<div class="ng-overlay ng-hide" ng-show="opened">
</div>
<div class="ng-gallery-content ng-hide" unselectable="on" ng-show="opened" ng-swipe-left="nextImage()" ng-swipe-right="prevImage()">
    <div class="uil-ring-css ng-hide" ng-show="loading"><div></div></div>
    <div class="header-section">
        <div class="header-text">
            <span class="heading issue-num-heading">
                <div class="header-title ng-binding">Issue no</div>
                <div class="header-content ng-binding">6530</div>
            </span>
            <span class="heading desc-heading">
                <div class="header-title ng-binding">Description</div>
                <div class="header-content ng-binding">Automation Test</div>
            </span>
            <span class="heading photo-added-heading">
                <div class="header-title ng-binding">Photos added by</div>
                <div class="header-content ng-binding"> ()</div>
            </span>
            <span class="heading status-heading">
                <div class="header-title ng-binding">Status</div>
                <div class="status-icon" id="statsIcon"></div>
                <div class="header-content ng-binding"></div>
            </span>
            <span class="heading date-heading">
                <div class="header-title ng-binding">Date</div>
                <div class="header-content ng-binding"></div>
            </span>
            <span class="close-heading" title="Close">
                <div class="close-btn" ng-click="closeGallery()"></div>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="" target="_blank" ng-show="showImageDownloadButton()" class="download-image ng-hide"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></a>
    <a class="close-popup" ng-click="closeGallery()"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
    <div class="nav-left previous-btn" title="Previous photo" ng-click="prevImage()"></div>
    <div class="current-image" ng-click="nextImage()" ng-show="!loading" ng-mousemove="showZoomControls($event)">
        <!-- hack to save the image -->
        <img class="current-image-save">
    </div>
    <div class="nav-right next-btn" title="Next photo" ng-click="nextImage()"></div>
    <span id="zoom-image" ng-mouseover="alwaysShowZoomControls()">
        <div>
            <!-- ngIf: !imageZoomed --><span class="zoom-out-grey ng-scope" ng-if="!imageZoomed"></span><!-- end ngIf: !imageZoomed -->
            <!-- ngIf: imageZoomed -->
            <span class="zoom-in" title="Zoom in" ng-click="zoomIn()"></span>
        </div>
    </span>
    <span class="info-text">
        <div><span class="photo-count ng-binding">1/0</span></div>
    </span>
    <div class="thumb-right-btn" ng-show="showThumbnails" ng-click="scrollRight(200)"></div>
    <div class="ng-thumbnails-wrapper">
        <div class="thumbnail-hide-icon" ng-show="showThumbnails" ng-click="hideThumbnailList()"></div>
        <div class="thumbnail-hide-header ng-binding" ng-click="hideThumbnailList()" ng-show="showThumbnails">
            Hide Thumbnails
        </div>
        <div class="thumbnail-show-icon ng-hide" ng-show="!showThumbnails" ng-click="showThumbnailList()"></div>
        <div class="thumbnail-show-header ng-binding ng-hide" ng-click="showThumbnailList()" ng-show="!showThumbnails">
            Show Thumbnails
        </div>
        <div class="ng-thumbnails slide-left" ng-show="showThumbnails">
            <!-- ngRepeat: i in images -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumb-left-btn" ng-show="showThumbnails" ng-click="scrollLeft(200)"></div>
</div></div><!-- ngIf: IssuesListItemCtrl.issue.attachments.length === 0 --><div class="ng-thumb no-thumbnail ng-scope" ng-if="IssuesListItemCtrl.issue.attachments.length === 0"></div><!-- end ngIf: IssuesListItemCtrl.issue.attachments.length === 0 --></div><div class="issue-status-group"><div class="issue-status open" ng-class="IssuesListItemCtrl.issue.status | lowercase"><div class="status-icon"></div><span class="ng-binding">OPEN</span></div></div><div class="content"><div class="issue-number-n-type line"><span class="issue-number ng-binding">6530</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span class="issue-type ng-binding">DEFECT</span></div><div class="description line"><span class="ng-binding">Automation Test</span></div><!-- ngIf: IssuesListItemCtrl.getAssignedTo() --><!-- ngIf: IssuesListItemCtrl.issue.dueDate --></div><div fm-photo-slide-show="" image-list="IssuesListItemCtrl.photoSlides" class-names="issue-list-photo-slide-show"></div></div>
```

Is there a better way to assert that only "Open" result is displayed? And btw, there is a scroll in the result.

Comment: Can you please give us the HTML source so that we can help you.

Comment: I am trying out all the approach mentioned below and posting my observations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are selecting the elements which are having the text OPEN. So, There is a possibility of item with different status.

There are two approaches which are good to test the filter.

**check status of each item:** Select the all element and check the status text is equal to OPEN or not as given below.

```
List<WebElement> lstItems = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='issue-status-group']/div/span [class='ng-binding']"));
for(WebElement eleItem: lstItems){
   Assert.assertEquals(eleItem.getText(),"OPEN");
 }
```

**check the count:** Second approach is that, find the all elements with text OPEN and check the count of it.

```
List<WebElement> lstItems = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[class='ng-binding' and text()='OPEN']"));
Assert.assertEquals(lstItems.size(), 10) //assumed no of open items are 10 here.
```

Comment: I get `cannot resolve symbol WebElements` error. Any idea why?

Comment: It should be list of web element not web elements. Updated the answer. please check.

Comment: The test is passing even if I change the expected to "PEN" instead of "OPEN"

Comment: But works fine if I use `"//div[@class='issue-status-group']//span"` as xpath. Is this correct?

Comment: If I try to add more filter (other than OPEN) when the code runs, it fails which is correct, but the error message is `"//div[@class='issue-status-group']//span"` instead of actual and expected. How can I make this to appear in actual/expected format?

Comment: Ok i figured that out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use java 8 streams API to filter the OPEN status :

```
boolean issueOtherThanOPENIsPresent = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='issue-status-group']//span")).stream().filter(element -> !element.getAttribute("innerText").trim().equals("OPEN")).findFirst().isPresent();
    if (issueOtherThanOPENIsPresent) {
        System.out.println("There are issues present which contains status other than OPEN");
    } else {
        System.out.println("All issues contains status OPEN");
    }
```

Here it is checking if there is any WebElement present that does not contains status "OPEN" , if it is present than it will return "true" otherwise "false".
Also you do not have to count every time the number of results that will appear.
It will filter the list according to any given text.

I hope it will simplify the answer also.

Comment: you are locating the element with the text OPEN and check the for the text OPEN. It always  true.

Comment: Hi Murthi , if you closely look at the line of code i have added "!"  i.e "not condition" before the actual comparison and it will return false if every element contains "OPEN"

Comment: I think now you got me.

Comment: No, your xpath is selecting the element with the text OPEN only. How do you expect the text is other OPEN?

Comment: Thanks Murthi. Now I got your point. You can then change the xpath to "//div[@class='issue-status-group']//span" . Now it will work.

Comment: Even after Open status is filtered, it still prints `There are issues present which contains status other than OPEN`. The same webpage has filters for other Status. Will that interfere? Does the xpath focus on the div as shown in the screenshot?

Comment: The "OPEN" defect div is : <div class="issue-status-group">
   <div class="issue-status open" ng-class="IssuesListItemCtrl.issue.status | lowercase">
    <div class="status-icon"></div>
    <span class="ng-binding">OPEN</span>
   </div>
  </div>    and according to this the xpath given is correct. You can print the innerText of elements that comes using this and can find what other status are shown. If you have selected other filters along with "OPEN" than only it will affect the result otherwise not. If that does not  helps you than we can discuss this. Ping me at sandpdangi13@gmail.com

Comment: Thanks. But how do I assert instead of printing it?

Comment: This also worked for me. But the marked answer concept was pretty simple. :)

Answer (score 0):

Taking into the consideration the HTML provided for the Open Result. Please find the code below with the explanation.

First store all the Result elements in the List:

```
  List<WebElement> statusFilterResult = driver.findElementsByXPath("//div[@class='issue-status-group']//div[@class='status-icon']/..//span");
```

Create a function which would verify the text of all the web elements in the list and will return true if the result is **open** for all the elements else it will return false.

```
private static Boolean verifyElementsInList(
        List<WebElement> statusFilterResult) {
    Boolean flag = true;
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    for(WebElement status: statusFilterResult){
        if(!status.getText().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Open")){
            flag = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

Add the code mentioned below in your main function after the line: **List statusFilterResult = driver.findElementsByXPath("//div[@class='issue-status-group']//div[@class='status-icon']/..//span");**

```
 Boolean result = verifyElementsInList(statusFilterResult);
      if(result){
          System.out.println("The status type is Open for all the issues on the page");
      }else{
          System.out.println("The status other than open is present on the page");
      }
```